# Mysql group by not using index

Tags: mysql, group-by, indexing

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE `APPLICATION_DEVICE_PUSHINFO` (
  `applicationId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `deviceId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `active` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `inactiveAsOf` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `lastSentOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `registeredOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `target` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `token` varchar(4096) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`applicationId`,`deviceId`),
  KEY `FKE7F2D58285EFFEAA_idx` (`deviceId`),
  KEY `index3` (`token`(255)) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FKE7F2D58285EFFEAA` FOREIGN KEY (`deviceId`) REFERENCES `DEVICES` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

If I execute the following query:

```
explain SELECT token FROM APPLICATION_DEVICE_PUSHINFO  group by token having count(deviceId) > 1;;
```

I get:

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'APPLICATION_DEVICE_PUSHINFO', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '7', 'Using temporary; Using filesort'
```

The null values belongs to possible keys etc.

Why the index for column token is not used ?

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions your use of `GROUP BY` is inappropriate. Perhaps you're after the `DISTINCT` operator? Also, don't use `SELECT *`. Instead name the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: Well, I guess MySQL looked at the tables and figured that as long as there's only 7 rows, there would be no benefit in using an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't have a WHERE clause, the query needs to process all rows (note that the HAVING clause is applied after the GROUP BY—hence it doesn't limit the row to be processed, just those that are returned).

If you need to touch all rows anyways, it's hard to gain any benefit from an index. Nevertheless it is possible to gain something if you'r able to do an Index Only Scan (IOS) and/or benefit from the pre-orderd data on disk.

However, an IOS might (not sure if MySQL considers the NOT NULL constraint) be prevented by the fact that you access the `deviceId` column which is not included in the index that could possibly used for this query (`index3`). Note that you need to have ONE index that covers all needs of the query to get an index only scan. However, if MySQL is smart enough and recognizes the NOT NULL constraint, this shouldn't be an issue. Otherwise, rewrite your query. e.g count(*) > 1.

In this particular case, your chances to get an IOS as bad anyways, because of the small size of the table (at least according to the optimizers estimates) (as already mentioned by Strawberry).

If you need to make sure it works with more rows as well, just fill up the table and see if it changes the execution plan. If not, change the query as mentioned above, try again. If not, return here and we'll see (post new execution plan).

You desire to execute this query via index is in principle reasonable. Making it work is another story :(